# Regex Replacing characters with zero

Tags: regex, replace, zero

I have the following string `3}HFB}4AF4}1 -M}1.`

I have searched for this string using the regex :

```
([0-9])(\})([A-Z]{3})(\})([0-9][A-Z]{2}[0-9])(\})([0-9])(\s\-)([A-Z])(\})([0-9]).
```

I want to replace the `}` with `0`. The Result I am looking for is `30HFB04AF401-M01`, any assistance is appriciated. The tool I am using is Regex Buddy

Comment: It would be really handy if you specify what language or program you want use this regex in. But usually it's just a matter of s/}/0/g.
BTW, all this parentheses in your regex are redundant.

Comment: you dont need to tell us the tool you are using..u need to tell us the `language` you are working with!

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ: AFAIK Regex Buddy uses the same regular expression dialect as .NET

Comment: @AdrianGrigore what are you trying to do here..replacing text using tools like regexBuddy,regexHero or language like c#,c++,java

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ: Not sure what you mean, but I am not trying to do anything. I am not the one who has opened this topic. You asked what language he is working with and I suggested that you could treat this OP as if he was asking about regular expressions in .NET.

Comment: Regex buddy supports a range of languages like .Net, Perl, etc. I am not sure of the language I am using on Regex Buddy but I think it is JGsoft

Comment: kompas could you elaborate how to use the replace syntax using $ for the s/}/0/g recommendation you provided

Comment: Reno, you need to address people using the @ sign otherwise they don't get notified (unless they are the questioner himself, or the person providing an answer). Furthermore, it would be nice if you replied on the answer instead of the question, and finally some upvotes and an accepted answer would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

## A *possible* solution

Problem solved? In JavaScript at least :-)

```
"3}HFB}4AF4}1 -M}1".replace(/\}/g, "0");
// "30HFB04AF401 -M01"
```

I'm missing the point, right?

Assuming the language is JavaScript, we can write something like

```
"dfghj456783}HFB}4AF4}1 -M}1fghjkl8765".replace(/(?:[\d\w\s]+)([0-9]}[A-Z]{3}}[0-9][A-Z]{2}[0-9]}[0-9] -[A-Z]}[0-9])(?:[\d\w\s]+)/g, function () {
    return arguments[1].replace(/}/g, "0");
});
```

What's possible in other languages though may be a different story.

Try [the home of RegexBuddy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tools.html) for details.

Comment: "I think more details are needed" would be a comment, using it as the title of you answer is not such a good idea. I don't know if you are missing the point though, the regexp given is simply the most simple one matching the entire string without specifying characters and decimals.

Comment: @owlstead Thanks for the suggestion to change the heading. Done. It's difficult to know what exceptions to add as of the time of posting. I'm assuming the target string is buried within a lot of very similar looking text, so went for a best guess. I appreciate the feedback. I'm new :-) Still finding my feet. Not new in time terms; new to contributing where I previously just read. Had to learn stuff before answering. Time to give back \o/

Comment: I'm still in the process of learning regex myself (that's why I am reading these questions), and I just discovered that braces `{ }` don't need to be escaped. So I've adjusted the code.

Answer (score 0):

So you've already got an expression to find instances of the string. Now you can either use groups to replace the characters, or you can use a separate regular expression over the string you found, simply replacing the `}` character within `group(0)` (which is the entire matched part of the input). I would certainly prefer the latter.

Fred seems to have created the replacement method for you already, so I won't repeat it here.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find a solution to the formating in the JGSoft Lanugage used by Regex Buddy, thanks to all that provided suggestions that helped me channel my thoughts in the right direction.

Solution(I am still a beginner with Regex hence the syntax might not be efficent, but it does the job!!)

Using Group Names instead of Regex assiging groups with backreference and `$` syntax.

Hence to replace `0` for `}` in the string `3}HFB}4AF4}1 -M}1` or any similar string. I used the following search and replacement syntax

Search : `(?<Gp1>([0-9]))(?:})(?<Gp2>([A-Z]){3})(?:})(?<Gp3>([0-9])([A-Z]{2})([0-9]))(?:})(?<Gp4>([0-9]))(?:\s-)(?<Gp5>([A-Z]))(?:})(?<Gp6>[0-9])`

Replace : `${Gp1}0${Gp2}0${Gp3}0${Gp4}-${Gp5}0${Gp6}`

Result : `30HFB04AF401-M01`